# iPhone - CLHeading to find direction

Tags: iphone, direction

In my iPhone application, I'm using using CLLocationManager to find the direction in which my iphone is pointing to. I'm using the property "heading". Its giving me x,y and z values.
How can I find from these values in which direction (north or south or east or west) I'm currently pointing to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`heading` is a `CLHeading` object. As one look in the documentation would have told you, it also has properties for the true and magnetic headings in degrees.

Comment: Thanks for the info. But when I'm using following code and trying to print the value, its always printing -1.00 all the time.

Comment: - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateHeading:(CLHeading *)newHeading 
{
 CLLocationDirection dir = [newHeading trueHeading];

Comment: How are you printing the result?

Answer (score 1):

you should use method `[locationManager startUpdateHeading]` to enable get the angle relative to the geographic North Pole or magnetic North Pole. Then you can get the value in

```
 - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateHeading:(CLHeading *)newHeading 
{
   NSLog(@"%f",newHeading.trueHeading);
}
```